# how to increase the max value keeping string lenght

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column numbers from 1 to 10000, they are stored like string with 8 characters, so number 1 is stored like 00000001 and 10000 is stored like 00010000.
I need to take the max for this column and increase by 1 in insert operations. but if I do:

`Max(column)+1`

I lost previous 0, so I have 10001 and not 00010001, how I can keep zeros?

Comment: Are you using that expression as part of an `INSERT`? If so, this seems like an XY problem. You'd be better off with an `IDENTITY`/`SEQUENCE` column and a (`PERSISTED`) computed column to "format" the value into a string with leading zeros.

Comment: Easy answer: Don't use a string column for this, use a numeric column.  Better yet, use an auto increment column and let SQL Server manage the sequence for you.

Comment: "I have a column numbers from 1 to 10000, they are stored like string" That's your first problem. If you have numbers, store them as numbers. If you need to pad them with leading zeroes, do that in the presentation layer.

Comment: @Larnu yes, I have to do that in an INSERT operation, unfortunately this is the column structure that I have to use and I can't change it

Comment: You really need to, @marko. What you have there will suffer from "race conditions", which will cause you some real problems down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FORMAT` function to format numbers:

```
SELECT FORMAT(1, '00000000') -- 00000001
```

Having said that, you should be storing numbers inside the database as-is and format them in the application.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using cast and replicate

```
  replicate('0', 8 - CONVERT(varchar(8),  max(CAST(column AS INT)) +1) ) + CONVERT(varchar(8),  max(CAST(column AS INT)) +1)
```

anyway you should take a look for identity in sqlserver for manage autoincrement column automatically

Comment: seems that it doesn't recognize lpad

Comment: answer updated ..  avoiding lpad and using replicate+